# passing selecteditems to a stored procedure from wpf datagrid through mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I implemented this already without using MVVM:

```
private void Del_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> cid = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRowView rw in Xgrid.SelectedItems)
        {

            cid.Add(rw[1].ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Deleting " + rw[1].ToString());
        }

        foreach (string cq in cid)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete_prc", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
            param1.ParameterName = "@Cid";
            param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            param1.Value = cq;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now I want to do this with MVVM.

I have customers.cs model class in which I have all the fields.
Now I don't know how to bind the check box so I am able to do this.

Xaml code:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox   IsChecked="{Binding Path=ViewModelBase.CheckAll, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Name="delete"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="rowNo." Width="60" Binding="{Binding RowNumber}" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomerID" Width="80" Binding="{Binding CustomerID}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CompanyName" Width="100" Binding="{Binding CompanyName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ContactName" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ContactName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ContactTitle" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ContactTitle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Address}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Width="100" Binding="{Binding City}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Region" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Region}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PostalCode" Width="100" Binding="{Binding PostalCode}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Country}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Phone}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fax" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Fax}"></DataGridTextColumn>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

So how to integrate this with mvvm. please help me doing this.

I want to know what to define in my viewmodel class and what should be the binding path to do this.

Comment: what you mean by what to define in viewmodel?

Comment: If you are asking how to get the button click in viewmodel , then use "Command" to do that.

Comment: I want to pass the selected items to my procedure. My procedure takes just the customer id. so initially i was passing the first column of every row selected through a loop by xgrid.selecteditems.

Comment: You have to bind the selected items property of your grid in the view model and then you can loop through each item of this property on your view model to perform any sql operations.

Answer (score 0):

In your DataGrid put a command like and you need to add

> xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

```
  <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="103" Width="517">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding Header,ElementName=id}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </DataGrid>
```

and access the Command in your **ViewModel** like this

```
  RelayCommand getitem;
    public RelayCommand GetItem
    {
        get
        {
            if(getitem == null)
            {
                getitem = new RelayCommand(p=>Executeyourcommand(p));
            }
            return getitem;
        }
    }


  void Executeyourcommand(object parameter)
    {
        // parameter is your CustomerID
       // do your work here
    }
```

your Command helper class

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> canexecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {

    }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> Execute, Predicate<object> Canexecute)
    {
        if(Execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        execute = Execute;
        canexecute = Canexecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if(canexecute == null)
            return true;
        else
            return canexecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

and ofc i didnt test the code and i hope this is your looking for